# If I buy and hold my ISOs pre-IPO, what access do I have to shareholder/board meetings?

Tags: united-states, employee-stock-options, shareholder-meeting

Let's say I have some vested incentive stock options with the startup that I work at (company and I are both in the USA). The company has not gone public at this point in time.

If I buy and hold my vested shares, what are my rights regarding shareholder meetings?

- Do I get to attend?
- Do I get to vote?
- Do I have access to meeting minutes?
- Are any of these required by law, or is it completely up to the company?
- Also, same questions regarding board meetings.

Comment: As a shareholder you have a lot of rights, but in my experiences startups are often either unaware or simply ignore them. [This article](https://www.wsj.com/amp/articles/own-startup-shares-know-your-rights-to-company-financials-1464082203) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is regulated by the company bylaws and depends on the rights assigned to the class of shares you own.

Generally, with voting shares, you're allowed to attend the shareholder meetings and cast the votes allocated to you.